# Non affine control?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, control-theory

Classically (most of what I have read), control problems are given, for example, in the form
$\dot x = f(x)+u$, where $u$ is the controller. I am interested in problems of the form $\dot x = f(x,t)u$. Would you please recommend some literature?

Comment: I cannot give you a reference to a book. But here is an observation that might help you. If $f(x,t)\neq 0$ for all $t$ and $x$, then you should be able to eliminate the dynamics with $$u = \dfrac{1}{f(x,t)}v.$$ For systems $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ you would do the same for each equation. Note, that with this control law your control effort will become very large for where $f(x,t)$ is very small. So this procedure is similar to dynamic inversion which can be applied to systems like $\dot{x}=f(x)+g(x)u$.

Comment: Thanks!, indeed I would like to tackle the case when f(x,t) is bounded but may be zero. Probably I can assume that f(x,t) is zero only on a set of measure zero... but I would be interested on not so restrictive cases, if they have been studied.

Comment: Notice that you can always make a non-affine control system affine by dynamic extension, i.e. adding an integrator after the actual controller (this might however affect achievable performance).

Comment: The more general system you consider, the fewer control approaches are applicable, sorry. Your solution also depends on your control goal and on the amount of information you have about $f$. Probably, you have an exact system under consideration? It will be simpler then.

Comment: Note also that your system is affine in control and is exactly in the form $\dot{x}=f_0(x,t)+g_0(x,t)u$, where you substitute $f_0=0$ and $g_0=f$. So most of the standard approaches should work under certain assumptions on $f$.